# Read Shapes (Rectangle,Square,Circle,Arrow etc), Clip Arts from MS Word File using java

Tags: java, apache-poi, shapes, aspose

I am able to get image from ms word table but unable to get shapes and clip-arts.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // The path to the documents directory.
    try {
        String dataDir = "E://test//demo.docx";
        generatePicturesAsImages(dataDir);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void generatePicturesAsImages(String sourcePath) {
    try {
        Document doc = new Document(sourcePath);
        ImageSaveOptions options = new ImageSaveOptions(SaveFormat.JPEG);
        options.setJpegQuality(100);
        options.setResolution(100);
        // options.setUseHighQualityRendering(true);
        List<ShapeRenderer> pictures = getAllPictures(doc);
        if (pictures != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pictures.size(); i++) {
                ShapeRenderer picture = pictures.get(i);
                String imageFilePath = sourcePath + "_output_" + i + ".jpeg";
                picture.save(imageFilePath, options);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static List<ShapeRenderer> getAllPictures(final Document document) throws Exception {
    List<ShapeRenderer> images = null;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    NodeCollection<DrawingML> nodeCollection = document.getChildNodes(NodeType.DRAWING_ML, Boolean.TRUE);
    if (nodeCollection.getCount() > 0) {
        images = new ArrayList<ShapeRenderer>();
        for (DrawingML drawingML : nodeCollection) {
            images.add(drawingML.getShapeRenderer());
        }
    }
    return images;
}
```

Above program is getting images from table so what should i add more to get the shapes.. Please suggest me any help will be appreciate !

Answer (score 1):

You are using an older version of Aspose.Words. If you want to use older version of Aspose.Words, please get the collection of Shape and DrawingML nodes using Document.getChildNodes in your getAllPictures method.

```
NodeCollection<DrawingML> drwingmlnodes = document.getChildNodes(NodeType.DRAWING_ML, Boolean.TRUE);

NodeCollection<Shape> shapenodes = document.getChildNodes(NodeType.SHAPE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Note that we removed the [DrawingML from our APIs in Aspose.Words 15.2.0](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/Public+API+Changes+in+Aspose.Words+15.2.0). If you want to use latest version of [Aspose.Words v16.5.0](http://www.aspose.com/downloads/words-family/java), please only use NodeType.SHAPE.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.